# How call a href in function Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need run

How do that?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Detal(date1, date2){
    <a id="various5" href="data/iframe.html?Detal_1=date1&Detal_2=date2">
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have HTML in JS. You will have to fetch element using `document.getElementById` and then either call its `.click()` or get its href and pass it to `window.open`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a  redirect use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```
function Detal(date1, date2){
    window.location.href = "data/iframe.html?Detal_1=" +date1+ "&Detal_2=" +date2;
}
```

If this is not the intent, you need to explain your issue in a lot more detail